# How to fetch values from Realtime Database Firebase that are not string values

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I have Linked my React Webapp to the Real-time Database of Firebase and am successfully fetching string values and displaying it on my webapp.

But when it comes to the Boolean values, I am not able to display them on the webapp interface. Although I am successful in fetching the data and can see the object received in the Console log.

```
export default class Webapp extends Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
      bloodConnect:'',
    }
    }

    componentWillMount=()=> {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('machineOne');
       rootRef.on('value', snap=>{
          this.setState({
            bloodConnect: snap.val(),
          });
      });
    }

    render() {
    console.log('this.state',this.state.bloodConnect)

    return ({this.state.bloodConnect.Entry1})}
```

Comment: My Firebase Structure is:  machineOne----->Entry1------>true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fetching them that must be a problem with your client code.

Have you tried to display the boolean value as a string?

```
{ String( value ) }
```

You can also use ternary operator such as :

```
{myBooleanValue ? 'Its true' : 'Its false'}
```